# How to allow when URL contain underscore character in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in CodeIgniter and have a problem with `URL`. When I open my URL like `www.abc.com/france` it's working fine but when URLs comes like `www.abc.com/united_state` the page open but all contents of page not shown properly. Also pagination not work(only single page shown). My controller code is

```
 $searchkey =$this->uri->segment(3);

     $searchkey  = urldecode(str_replace('_',' ',$searchkey));
     $checkin =$this->uri->segment(4);
    $checkout = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $newkey=$this->uri->segment(5);
                 }

if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/', $checkin) && preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/', $checkout))
    {
        //echo "hello";
        $last1=$last1+2;
        switch($last1)
{
case 5:


$searchkey=$this->uri->segment(3);


$column = "CountryName";$master = "country";$master2 = "CountryName";
$getdata = $this->searchdata_model->get_listing_data_list($column,$searchkey,$checkin,$checkout,$master,$newkey);
$latest_listing = $this->searchdata_model->get_lastest_properties($searchkey,$master2);
$data['latest_listing'] = $latest_listing;
break;
```

I think the problem is in preg_match function.

Answer (score 1):

Allow the underscore character in `config/config.php` file

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-';
```